# Is it possible to strongly type an object's keys based on array values?

Tags: typescript

In order to make use of normalized data, I've constructed an object whose keys can only be a list of numbers in a given array.  Is there some way to reflect this in typing so that, if I try to index into the object using a non-array-value key, I get an error (other than the error that this value may be undefined).

In other words, for this object of type Foo:

```
 const x:Foo = {                                                 
   allIds: [1,3],                                                                  
   structured: {                                                                    
     1: "foo",          
     3: "bar"           
    } 
 }
```

Is it possible to construct Foo in such a way that the following errors because 2 is not in the array allIds?

```
const z = x.structured[2]
```

I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to do the trick as the index signature widens to "number":

```
 interface Foo {                                                    
   allIds: number[]                                                               
   structured: Record<Foo["allIds"][number],string>                   
 }
```

Any help much appreciated.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN7L-gwo4k04gKHzgBtqBJAEwGcAuZEAVwFsAjaAbQC6ZEaLHj8lPEzBQOCMBygQGbAEoQE6KAwA8GdPwBENesyOD%20nXtEEAaGVFABzAHwSClAL4fff-6JSAcEh-pRaIDLIAB4sBsgAvDihKXhBpoysyPwAjHYAzPapxRJBjvKKyqrJJbWBhDlsRjCYRnZkQXj5TTxwUEYinT7eoeTkAPTjyHTIAO5w4MhgABbATEtY0FDayHwIcBxMKABMyGvs6GBnIEvLKH1QcACeyBnM5BFRAF6JMQB05QUShU-GOgiAA)

Clarification: Assume the values of allIds are set statically in the code, i.e., do not vary at runtime.

Comment: Do the values in `allIds` get determined at runtime? Do they vary at runtime? If so, no, you can't do this with the type system. (You *can* do it at runtime with a proxy.)

Comment: Good point; I've clarified the question. Out of curiosity, @t-j-crowder, can you give me a pointer on what you mean by doing it with a proxy at runtime?

Comment: With a `Proxy` object, you can have a [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set) handler (and a `get` handler if relevant) and reject attempts to set (or get) properties with numeric names that aren't in `allIds`.

Comment: (FWIW, I go into `Proxy` -- and the related `Reflect` -- in some depth in Chapter 14 of my new book, details in my profile if you're interested. But that won't help with the strong typing you're trying to do above.)

Comment: @sam256 was your question answered? if so please accept so this question can be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could do is not type `x` with an interface `Foo` but use [const assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions). This will prevent the automatic typewidening of `allIds` to be `number[]` and instead be `readonly [1,3]`.

```
 const x = {                                                 
   allIds: [1,3] as const,                                                                  
   structured: {                                                                    
     1: "foo",          
     3: "bar"           
    } 
 }
```

I assume your object `x` is split into two parts anyway, one with the statically defined  `allIds` and the other possibly dynamic part `structured`. We can then expand your interface `Foo` by a generic parameter `AllowedIndices` and provide that with the type of `allIds` which we asserted as const.

```
const allIds = [1,3,4] as const;

 interface Foo<AllowedIndices extends readonly number[]> {                                                    
   structured: Partial<Record<AllowedIndices[number], string>>                
 }                                                                                  
                                                                                    
 const x: Foo<typeof allIds> = {                                                 
   structured: {                                                                    
     1: "foo",          
     3: "bar"           
    } 
 }                  

const z = x.structured[2] // error
```

[Link to Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwQSQCYRgXhgbQIwA0AzAQCwC68GokUA3AFAMwCWYUApgE4BmcwHGADEQIADwBBJCADuHVMjCoWAjBwAenJRi4c4qcAgCeMMAFcAtgCNuOcgD4YAbxiu37j56-efX5q+guM2AoM11UAC4YAAU4LigWRDEAJQ5QLlRJaTkFJRUOCBxza25yAhhAtgBze0dfD2YAX3qW1rb2jph-Tp7evu9mGmgYdSiRcSgjAAcOEB54JDQIR2wXfvWGt0Dg0PCotY3D3u7XPCiAIh5Rc-KfE5giC6s48-qT5qaepiHYAC8sEYAOm2ITC8hwACZKAB6aEwbhcEBcGBAA)

**Notes on the example:**

I have added another index `4` to exemplify the use of `Partial<T>`: indices in `allIds` don't necessarily need to appear as keys in `x.structured`.

Comment: That. Is. Nice.